# Recovery Mode: Backup options not showing

Tags: rooting, backup, rom-manager, lg-g2

I want to put a custom ROM on my LG G2.

I have successfully applied root permissions using IORoot v25. However I am unable to create a backup of the stock ROM.

I have tried several ways using the `ROM Manager` app (v5.5.37):

1. Go to `ROM Manager > Recovery Setup > [Install or Update] ClockwordModrecovery`. Then tap `Reboot into Recovery`. The phone reboots into the recovery menu, but no options to back up are listed. (So I choose option to reboot).
2. With CWM Recovery still set, I tap  "Backup Current ROM" (underneath it says the backup directory will be `/mnt/shell/emulated/clockworkmod/backup`. Again, it boots into the recovery menu without any backup options so I select reboot. Yet nothing appears in the `/mnt/shell directory`.
3. Configure ROM Manager to use `TWRP recovery`. Then in ROM Manager, tap  option to go to recovery mode. Yet again, no backup options are listed, so yet again I choose option to reboot.
4. With TWRP Recovery still set, I tap  "Backup Current ROM" (underneath it says the backup directory will be `/sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/0225b99d9a5159f0`. Surprise surprise, no backup options, and no directory `/sdcard/TWRP`.

What am I doing wrong?

From what I understand, what I am seeing is the "stock" recovery [program/menu], and neither the TWRP nor the CWM recovery menus are showing. Perhaps they're failing to install, or failing to be run or something? The logs in the app `SuperSU` which handles root requests do not give any hints - I can find no mention of CWM or TWRP recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was correct - the stock recovery was not being substituted for a custom recovery.

I have since tried a number of things:

First I tried installing the "FreeGee" app. Trying to install a custom recovery resulted in the error "Your devices specific software version of D80220d is not currently supported".

Second, I tried following [this guide](http://theunlockr.com/2013/11/03/flash-custom-recovery-lg-g2-versions-video/) resulted in the error:

```
Loki tool v2.1
[-] Loki aboot version does not match device.
1|root@g2:/data/local/tmp # exit
1|shell@g2:/ $
```

What eventually worked was downloading the AutoRec .apk for the LG G2 D802 and installing it using adb:

adb install D802_AutoRec.apk

I downloaded the .apk from [here](http://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=13763). TWRP recovery was installed successfully. More information on AutoRec is [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2715496).